# Contact importing in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

Can anyone suggest me how to work with contact importing in iOS sdk?
I mean to import the address book into my iOS application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than try to import the contacts, why don't you use the address book.

Have a look at the [AddressBook Framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html).